How to create the same sha1 hash in Python3 as Maraidb sha1 hash?
I'm trying to create the same sha1 hash as the sha1 hash generated in Mariadb for equality look ups.
I've tried this:
Python file
import hashlib
columns    = ["one", "two", "three"]
column_str = ",".join(columns)
result     = hashlib.sha1(column_str.encode()).hexdigest()

Mariadb column
hash char(40) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (sha(concat_ws(',', 'one', 'two', 'three'))) STORED;

But the result does not give the same hash as Mariadb generated hash.
Why am I not getting the same result?
P.S.
I've also converted the column to use the UTF8 character set.

What are the two hashes you get, which one is the correct one, and why do you ask us about that one?

The correct hash exists in Mariadb. I want the python sha1 hash to be the same as the hash in Mariadb.

I don't see any difference between Python and MariaDB. In Python:
>>> import hashlib
>>> print(hashlib.sha1(','.join(['one', 'two', 'three']).encode()).hexdigest())
0b44bcad5f54f1ac373269c523c52f4d428a7dce

In MariaDB:
MariaDB [example]> select sha(concat_ws(',', 'one', 'two', 'three'));
+--------------------------------------------+
| sha(concat_ws(',', 'one', 'two', 'three')) |
+--------------------------------------------+
| 0b44bcad5f54f1ac373269c523c52f4d428a7dce   |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

Both implementations return the same hash value.
If you are seeing different behavior, please update your question to include a complete minimal, reproducible example -- code that we can run locally to reproduce the behavior you're seeing.

Just to be clear, the actual Python code in your question produces the same value as well:
>>> import hashlib
>>> columns    = ["one", "two", "three"]
>>> column_str = ",".join(columns)
>>> result     = hashlib.sha1(column_str.encode()).hexdigest()
>>> result
'0b44bcad5f54f1ac373269c523c52f4d428a7dce'

